# Call a function onClick and passing it a value from the element's data-* attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have links like this:

```
<li><a href="#" data-value="Codes">Get codes</a></li>
<li><a href="#" data-value="Product">Get products</a></li>
```

How can I make it so that when I click on the link then a function gets called passing the value that's contained in data-value?

```
function refreshGrid(value) { }
```

Comment: Java is not the same as JavaScript. For clarity make sure you get the distinction right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following:

```
$('li > a[href="#"][data-value]').click(function (e) { // On click of all anchors with a data-value attribute and a href of # that are immediate children of li elements (nb this selector can be modifed to suit your needs)
  e.preventDefault(); // prevent the default (navigate to href)
  refreshGrid($(this).data('value')); // call your refreshGrid function with the value contained in the 'data-value' attribute
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var linkValue = $("li a").attr("data-value");
```

## Edit: Better example

```
$("li a").click(function () {
    var myDataValue = $(this).attr("data-value");
    refreshGrid(myDataValue);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

[here's a quick sample](http://jsfiddle.net/b2Qpr/1/)

```
$('ul').on('click','a[data-value]',function(){
    refreshGrid(this.getAttribute('data-value'));
    return false;
});
```